# Reading makefiles. Meaning of symbols

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to learn how to read makefiles and came across this one. My question is referring to the rule with target `%.c`. On the first command. where it says

```
 %.c: %.psvn  psvn2c_core.c psvn2c_state_map.c psvn2c_abstraction.c
    ../psvn2c  $(PSVNOPT) --name=$(*F)  < $< > $@
```

What does `$(*F) < $ < > $@` mean? I have posted the whole makefile below.

```
   CC = gcc
        CXX = g++
        OPT = -g -Wall -O3 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -std=c++11
        PSVNOPT = --no_state_map --no_backwards_moves --history_len=0 --abstraction --state_map 

psvn2c_core.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_core.c ./psvn2c_core.c

psvn2c_state_map.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_state_map.c ./psvn2c_state_map.c

psvn2c_abstraction.c:
    cp ../psvn2c_abstraction.c ./psvn2c_abstraction.c

%.c: %.psvn  psvn2c_core.c psvn2c_state_map.c psvn2c_abstraction.c
    ../psvn2c  $(PSVNOPT) --name=$(*F)  < $< > $@
    rm -f ./psvn2c_core.c ./psvn2c_state_map.c ./psvn2c_abstraction.c
```

I want to understand this as a first step towards learning how to run a c++ debugger such as gdb with eclipes or visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that begins with a `$` in a makefile is a variable reference (or, in GNU make, a built-in function), unless it's escaped with another `$` (i.e., is `$$`).  The name of the variable can either be a single character, like `$@`, `$A`, etc., or it can be one or more characters enclosed in parentheses or braces, like `$(@)`, `${A}` (the same as the last ones), `$(FOO)`, `${FOO}`, etc.

The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) has lots of information about all the pre-defined and special variables.  These odd-looking variables in particular are [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

If it's not a variable, and it's part of a recipe, then it's sent to the shell, so you should look at the shell documentation to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to say that < means pipe the input in from and then $< is the first file in the list of dependancies. and > means pipe output to and $@ is the output file ie. the file on the left hand side of the : symbol?